# google compute engine with static ip address

Tags: google-compute-engine, static-ip-address

I've just changed my compute engine instance to have a static ip.
before changing it I could perform the following command and in cases of erros see the problem: `http://<static_ip_address>:<port_id>/<foo_name>`
debug is set to true, and I'm running debug server with `python manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:<port_id>`, and I have declared a firewall rule for the special port.

after changing to static ip i'm getting the following error in browser but the application works file and does call the service

```
The webpage at http://<static_ip_address>:<port_id>/<foo_name> might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 312 (net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT): Unknown error.
```

how can I see the debug information?